# Can I split by Delimiter and Create New Row in SharePoint List?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list that tracks the Form result. If user selects > 1 item, the list will be shown as below.

Is it possible to generate 2 separate rows of information in SharePoint instead of showing them together as 1 long list? That would allow me to indicate different status for different request.

[image: Original Output]

The Final Result should be like

**Name of BI Application | Qlikview**

Qlikview, GPR Dashboard

Qlikview, Sales Dashboard

Qlikview, GPR Dashboard

No Column will have more than 1 choice of item

Answer (score 1):

You can create a few conditions and check if it contains certain text. In your example, you would initialize a boolean variable called "GPRDashboard" and the value would be something like:

```
@{contains(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rd27f91c7ca5fl193546cc81c3131995e'], 'GPR Dashboard')}
```

and then create another variable "SalesDashboard" and do the same thing

```
@{contains(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/rd27f91c7ca5fl193546cc81c3131995e'], 'Sales Dashboard')}
```

and repeat this for every option you have. Then you can create some nested IF conditions like the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! So if let's say I have 5 different file names, then I'd need to create 5 different conditions to check on it?

Comment: Exactly! You have to create 5 separate conditions